# Count the number of sub tags from XML in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, xml, sqlxml

XML sent from code to the SQL server. My XML as looks like this:

```
Declare @MainXML XML=
    '<root>
    <a>JJ</a>
    <a>KK</a>
    </root>'
```

From the above xml, I want to store 2 as being the count of child elements "a" under a column1 in SQL.

```
Column1
-------
   2
```

Can you help me with this?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest doing this on the database side, to be frank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this with `xpath`:

```
select @MainXML.query('count(root/a)')
```

<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72/12)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `mssql server` then you can take advantage of the [OPENXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175160.aspx) support. You can get the count of the `a` nodes by using a `SELECT` on the parsed XML:

```
Declare @MainXML XML =
    '<root>
    <a>JJ</a>
    <a>KK</a>
    </root>'

SELECT COUNT(MainXML.A.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')) AS Cnt
FROM @MainXML.nodes('root/a') MainXML(A)
```