# Using a Count within an OpenXML query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a very large XML document which I am loading into SQL and then trying to parse to add to the end of an existing table.

My code so far is: 
'

```
INSERT INTO XMLAttempt1(XMLData, LoadedDateTime)
SELECT CONVERT(XML, Bulkcolumn) AS Bulkcolumn, getdate()
from openrowset(bulk 'filepath.xml', Single_clob) as x;

select * from XMLAttempt1

DECLARE @XML as XML, @hdoc int, @doc nvarchar(MAX); 
SELECT @xml = XMLDATA FROM XMLAttempt1;
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @XML;
  Select * 
  FROM  OPENXML (@hdoc, 'CxXMLResults/Query/Result', 1) 
  WITH  (ID     int     '../@id',
    @NodeId     INT     @NodeId',
    ProjectID   int '../../@ProjectId',
    ScanId      int '../../@ScanId');
```

The XML is formatted as:

```
    <Result NodeId="635920047"  lots of other info>
      <Path ResultId="63592" PathId="47" SimilarityId="-1924977021">
        <PathNode>
         <FileName></FileName>
          <Line>292</Line>
          <Column>82</Column>
          <NodeId>1</NodeId>
          <Name>SelectedValue</Name>
          <Type></Type>
          <Length>13</Length>
          <Snippet>
            <Line>
              <Number>292</Number>
              <Code>  stuff;</Code>
            </Line>
          </Snippet>
        </PathNode>
[next x numbers of PathNode] 
</Path>
</Result> 
<Result NodeId="635920048"

[etc until the next QueryId]
```

I've seen this post ([Count the number of sub tags from XML in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132560/count-the-number-of-sub-tags-from-xml-in-sql/30132881#30132881)) but I can't get it to work and i'm thinking thats because of where I'm trying to use it - I'm not getting the syntax right.

```
DECLARE @XML as XML, @hdoc int, @doc nvarchar(MAX); 
SELECT @xml = XMLDATA FROM XMLAttempt1;
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @XML;
  Select * 
  FROM  OPENXML (@hdoc, 'CxXMLResults/Query/Result', 1) 
  WITH  (ID     int '../@id',
    @XML.query('count(@NodeId') INT '@NodeId',
    ProjectID   int '../../@ProjectId',
    ScanId      int '../../@ScanId');
```

But it says incorrect syntax at @XML

Current results:

```
ID      NodeID       ProjectID  ScanId
427 635920047   20336   63592
427 635920048   20336   63592
427 635920049   20336   63592
427 635920050   20336   63592
427 635920051   20336   63592
427 635920052   20336   63592
```

What I want to end up with is:

```
ID      Count ofNodes       ProjectID  ScanId
427   6                   20336 63592
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not show enough of your XML, so this needs some amount of guessing...

But first: `FROM OPENXML` is outdated and should not be used any more (rare exceptions exist). Rather use [XML's native methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-data-type-methods?view=sql-server-2017).

As mentioned before, this is wild guessing

```
SELECT @XML.value('(/CxXMLResults/Query/@id)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS id
      ,@XML.value('count(/CxXMLResults/Query/Result/@NodeId)','int') AS CountOfNodes
      ,@XML.value('(/CxXMLResults/@ProjectId)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS ProjectId
      ,@XML.value('(/CxXMLResults/@ScanId)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS ScanId
```

Some hints:

- *Backward-navigation* (What you do with `../../` is known as very slow, try to avoid it.
- I assume, that there are no namespaces involved (`xmlns="something"`)
- I assume that there is `<CxXMLResults>` and `<Query>` around the XML you show us and that the values for id, ProjectId and ScanId are living in parts you did not show.
- You might have to adjust the XPathes

Comment: Hi - Thank you! I worked out what I was doing wrong - I can't do a count in openXML because it's not stored in a table - so I'm parsing it into a staging table and then doing the count from there and copying into my actual table.

All the googling I did said to use OpenXML, so I'll look into the XML value stuff - thanks for the links :) 

I've got it working now, but if I can make it streamlined and quicker, that's a win!

Comment: @BeckyG Well, you can do this if it works for you. If this is a *one-time-action* it should not really matter how you solve this. But the `FROM OPENXML` approach is - for sure - not the best choice here. Native XML methods will be much better in performance and pressure on your machines...